# How to insert text file into visual basic listview with each 4 lines of text starting a new item

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, listview, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to insert a text file into a listview, with each 4 lines of text starting a new item. an example of the text is,

Richard Jones

35

1750

85.7

Bob Rogers

52

2040

120.4

jason alexander

64

1650

82.4

I am trying to have it so the text is entered in 4 columns, name, age, height, weight, then once the next name is there it starts a new item. I can do this successfully but with a dividing line that I use to detect it. e.g. "--"

Here is my current code:

Dim openfile = New OpenFileDialog() With {.Filter = "Text (*.Text)|*.txt"}
Dim rtb As New RichTextBox
If (openfile.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then

```
        rtb.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText(openfile.FileName)

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each line As String In rtb.Lines

            If line = "--" Then

                Dim item As New ListViewItem
                item.Text = rtb.Lines(i + 1)
                item.SubItems.Add(rtb.Lines(i + 2))
                item.SubItems.Add(rtb.Lines(i + 3))
                item.SubItems.Add(rtb.Lines(i + 4))
                ListView1.Items.Add(item)
            Else

            End If
            i += 1
        Next

    End If
```

Comment: Well, fist thing you're needing to do is decide exactly what the criteria for new items is.  You say Name, but is that every 4th line, or a line with only alpha characters.  I would also suggest you might find it easier to parse your text file into a list of a class object and bind your list view to that

Comment: In this case, ListView is not a good choice. Do you consider using DataGridView or TreeView ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a ListView here is some code.
But as suggested you would be better off using a DataGridView.

```
    Public Sub LoadLB()
    Dim strData(12) As String
    strData = {"", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}
    Dim allMo As String
    For i As Integer = 1 To 12
        allMo = i & " - " & strData(i)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(allMo)
    Next
End Sub
```

Notice this line of code `allMo = i & " - " & strData(i)`and convert it to your needes